# R Rstudio problemas para instalar el package mapdeck y googlePolylines

Tags: r, rstudio

Cuando intento instalar el package mapdeck en Rstudio, me indica que necesito el package googlePolylines, pero no consigo instalar este último. El error que sale es el siguiente:

> package ‘googlePolylines’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> libs
>
> g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include
>   -I"/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
>
> g++ -m64 -std=gnu++0x -I/usr/include/R -DNDEBUG -I../inst/include
>   -I"/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include" -I"/usr/lib64/R/library/BH/include" -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -c encode.cpp -o encode.o
>
> encode.cpp: In function ‘void encode_vector(std::ostringstream&,
>   std::ostringstream&, Rcpp::List, Rcpp::CharacterVector&, int)’:
>   encode.cpp:175: error: conversion from
>   ‘Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19, Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’ to ‘double’
>   is ambiguous
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:73:
>   note: candidates are: Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator int() const [with int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:72:
>   note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator bool() const [with int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:67:
>   note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator U() const [with U = double, int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage] encode.cpp:176: error:
>   conversion from ‘Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy<19,
>   Rcpp::PreserveStorage>’ to ‘double’ is ambiguous
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:73:
>   note: candidates are: Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator int() const [with int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:72:
>   note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator bool() const [with int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage]
>   /home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/vector/generic_proxy.h:67:
>   note:                 Rcpp::internal::generic_proxy::operator U() const [with U = double, int RTYPE = 19,
>   StoragePolicy = Rcpp::PreserveStorage] make: *** [encode.o] Error 1
>   ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘googlePolylines’
>
> removing
>   ‘/home/arubio/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.4/googlePolylines’
>
> Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>   ‘googlePolylines’ had non-zero exit status
>
> The downloaded source packages are in
>     ‘/tmp/RtmpwwAJSv/downloaded_packages’

No he encontrado casi nada de información sobre estos packages, agradecería si alguien me pudiera ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Ana, acabo de instalar googlePolylines sin problemas en Fedora 28 (por el mensaje de error veo que estás usando Fedora o alguno de la flia), así que se puede. El error que te pasa al final no es muy claro, pero por mi experiencia pueden ser una de dos cosas: 1. Está mal instalado o fallando `Rcpp`, que es la librería de enlace entre R y C++. Prueba actualizando o reinstalando esa librería desde R. (cont.)

Comment: 2. Quizás te falte alguna dependencia externa que CRAN no maneja y tienes que instalar con el administrador de paquetes de tu Linux (`dnf` en el caso de Fedora). Prueba que estén instalados **en R** los paquetes `sp` y `gdal`, que son paquetes básicos para SIG en R de los que dependen muchos otros. Si no tienes instalados estos paquetes avisa por aquí, te podríamos ayudar a instalar las dependencias externas necesarias para que CRAN pueda instalarlos. Yo tengo esos paquetes instalados (y vaya a saber cuantos más ;) y pude instalar sin problemas googlePolylines. Suerte!

Comment: Verifica también tener instalada en R la librería `BH`. Por el mensaje del compilador también está requiriendo  algunos archivos .h (encabezados o headers)  que dependen de esa librería. `installed.packages()[,1] ` te regresa un vector con los paquetes instalados en R.

Comment: Gracias @mpaladino, creo que el problema es lo que comentas sobre `sp` y `gdal`, porque he probado y tanto el paquete `Rcpp` como el `BH` no me han dado problemas. Me podrías decir cómo instalar las dependencias para poder instalarlos desde CRAN? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que falten algunas librerías básicas para el manejo de polígonos y cartografía a nivel sistema operativo.

## Instalación de librerías para cartografía en R con Fedora28

Para lograr instalar `sp` y `gdal` (necesarias para importar capas de polígonos) hay que instalar una serie de librerías directamente en linux.

**Desde la terminal del sistema** deberías usar los siguientes comandos:

```
sudo dnf install geos geos-devel
sudo dnf install gdal gdal-devel 
sudo dnf install proj-devel
sudo dnf install proj-nad
sudo dnf install proj-epsg
```

Como estás usando `sudo` va a pedirte la contraseña. Esos paquetes están en el repositorio oficial de Fedora, así que no debería haber problemas.

Después de instalar esas librerías a nivel sistema ya podrías instalar `sp` y `gdal` desde CRAN. Luego `googlePolylines`.

Nos comentas como te fue.

Saludos!

Comment: Me ha funcionado, muchas gracias!